# Total indexed is zero with 302 status

Tags: google-search-console

I'm using Google Webmaster Tools to manage my site SEO; even with 600 articles my total indexed pages is *zero*.

When I use "Fetch as Google" I get the following.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>302 Found</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Found</h1>
    <p>The document has moved <a href="http://example.com">here</a>.</p> <hr />
  </body>
</html>
```

My site is made with Drupal 7, and the Boost module.

Is that caused by a wrong configuration? If so, how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried to submit sitemap to Google? Try if this helps, also: http://drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap

Comment: yes of course,the site is verified and all my sitemaps are submitted to google

Comment: Did you tried it without Boost? I tried to implement boost too, but ended up using Varnish cache (better imo, if you can)

Comment: @HoverFusion you say that maybe the Boost module is the source of the problem?

Comment: @HoverFusion what do you mean by imo,and please give me your site url to take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a different domain either registered or for testing with Google Webmaster Tools.

e.g `example.com` vs `www.example.com`

When the bot requests `example.com`, it is redirected to `www.example.com` with an HTTP `302 Found` reponse.

The solution would be to register the same preferred domain with Google Webmaster Tools that is used for regular site visitors.

As for 0 pages of a new site being indexed in Google, give it time. If you've registered the sitemap, and signed up for Google Analytics, the googlebot will arrive soon. It can take a couple of weeks.

Comment: For the 302 found i will give you an ansewer afetr testing it,and for the 0 page my website is 4 months old

Comment: I've seen it take up to 6 months before for Google indexing to occur. It tends to be shorter these days though. Test the index also by searching site:example.com in Google.

Comment: In Webmastertools->Configuration->Setting->Preffered domain my own preffered domain is not set "Don't set a preferred domain" and when i try to change it to www.example.com or just example.com i get the following messgae: "Part of the process of setting a preferred domain is to verify that you own http://sahara-question.com/. Please verify http://sahara-question.com/." what  does it mean?and how to fix that? thank you very much

Comment: You need to go through the verification process with the new adjusted domain. The instructions are explained in Google Webmaster Tools.

Comment: Did you mean i delete my old site account in google webmaster tools and recreate another one

Answer (score 1):

No you don't have to recreate a new account for your site on google weblaster tools,just wait for few days or weeks and it will be ok .
For the boost some make sure that your boost code gotten from the module generator is well copied before

> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}
>   !-d RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico RewriteRule ^ index.php

test it and everything will be ok

Answer (score 0):

I found the ansewer:
It's the Boost module,i had misconfigured it, i should put the Boost code above this line not under it:

> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
>   RewriteRule ^ index.php [L

For more details please see this post: http://drupal.org/node/1881070